# Check whether a JTA transaction is successfully committed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, eclipselink, entitylisteners

Is there a way to check if the current transaction is committed or not in JPA entity listeners something like the following?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityListener {

    @Inject
    private Event<EntityEvent> event;
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    @PostRemove
    public void onChange(Entity entity) {

        // This is only a piece of pseudo code.
        if (userTransaction.isComitted()) {
            // Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Entity listeners in JPA 2.1 are treated as CDI beans that depend upon CDI injection(s) and a transaction context along with CDI is available in entity listeners. Those injections are therefore possible in the entity listener (with or without the annotation `@ApplicationScoped`). The JPA 2.1 specification states,

> The persistence provider is only required to support CDI injection
>   into entity listeners in Java EE container environments. If the CDI is
>   not enabled, the persistence provider must not invoke entity listeners
>   that depend upon CDI injection.
>
> When invoked from within a Java EE environment, the callback listeners
>   for an entity share the enterprise naming context of the invoking
>   component, and **the entity callback methods are invoked in the
>   transaction and security contexts** of the calling component at the
>   time at which the callback method is invoked.
>
> For example, if a transaction commit occurs as a result of the normal
>   termination of a session bean business method with transaction
>   attribute `RequiresNew`, the `PostPersist` and `PostRemove` callbacks
>   are executed in the naming context, the transaction context, and the
>   security context of that component.

Does there exist a way to know whether a transaction is successfully committed or not in JPA entity listener so that a different action or no action at all could be taken accordingly?

I expect a transaction does not get finished in its entirely as soon as a commit occurs and hence, there should exist a way to see, if a commit occurs or not especially, I am looking for a way to simulate a transaction-wide event i.e. an event triggering at the end of a transaction giving the status of the transaction whether the transaction is committed or rolled back.

Using GlassFish Server 4.1 / Java EE 7 having EclipseLink 2.6.0 (JPA 2.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer [the CDI specification docs](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#transactional_observer_methods).

> ### 10.4.5. Transactional observer methods
>
> Transactional observer methods are observer methods which receive event notifications during
>   the before or after completion phase of the transaction in which the
>   event was fired. If no transaction is in progress when the event is
>   fired, they are notified at the same time as other observers.
>
> - A before completion observer method is called during the before    completion phase of the transaction.
> - An after completion observer method is called during the after    completion phase of the transaction.
> - An after success observer method is called during the after    completion phase of the transaction, only when the transaction
>     completes successfully.
> - An after failure observer method is called during the after    completion phase of the transaction, only when the transaction fails.
>
> The enumeration `javax.enterprise.event.TransactionPhase` identifies
>   the kind of transactional observer method:
>
> ```
> public enum TransactionPhase {
>     IN_PROGRESS,
>     BEFORE_COMPLETION,
>     AFTER_COMPLETION,
>     AFTER_FAILURE,
>     AFTER_SUCCESS
> }
> ```
>
> A transactional observer method may be declared by specifying any
>   value other than `IN_PROGRESS` for `during`:
>
> ```
> void onDocumentUpdate(@Observes(during=AFTER_SUCCESS) @Updated Document doc) { ... }
> ```