# JPA Entity out of sync with database using multiple sessions

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I have a Java EE application with JPA implemented using Eclipselink. I have implemented a basic user login system using the ExternalContext session map. However it seems that often a session becomes out of sync with the database.

The basic process is 
1. User A Creates a BidOrder entity. 
2. User B creates an AskOrder entity.
3. A monitor checks the two orders match and if so creates an OrderBook entity
4. The changes are Pushed to all users (using Primefaces 5.3 Push)

When I check the prices I use this method in my SessionScoped backing bean for my main view:

```
public void findLatestPrices()
 {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "findLatestPrices with user {0} ",user.getUserId());

    findAllOrderBooks(); 
    latestPricesId = new ArrayList<String>();
    setLatestPricesResults(request.findLatestPrices());
     for (Iterator<OrderBook> it = orderBookResults.iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
     {
        OrderBook orderBook = it.next(); 
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Found {0} orderbook price", orderBook.getPrice());
     }

     logger.log(Level.INFO, "End of findLatestPrices with user {0} ",user.getUserId());
 }
```

This calls my RequestScoped Stateful ejb:

```
public List<OrderBook> findLatestPrices() {
        List<OrderBook> orderBooks;
        List<OrderBook> orderBooksFiltered;

        Map<Member, OrderBook> map = new LinkedHashMap<Member, OrderBook>();

         try {
             orderBooks = em.createNamedQuery(
                     "findAllOrderBooks").setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH")
                     .getResultList();
             for (Iterator<OrderBook> it = orderBooks.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                 OrderBook orderBook = it.next();
                 Member member = orderBook.getBidOrderId().getMember();
                 map.put(member, orderBook);

                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "findLatestPrices orderbook price : {0}", 
                            orderBook.getPrice());
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "findLatestPrices orderbook bidorder member : {0}", 
                            orderBook.getBidOrderId().getMember().getMemberId());
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "findLatestPrices orderbook lastupdate : {0}", 
                            orderBook.getLastUpdate());
             }
...}
```

I create the EntityManager in the above bean in the following way:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

From the logging I can see that sessions return data that is out of sync with the database, i.e. single results when I'd expect two etc. As you can see I've tried setHint to refresh the cache. I've also tried @Cacheable(false) on my OrderBook entity and @Cache(refreshAlways=true) but to no avail.

I'm sending a push event in the @PostPersist of the entity that is created (OrderBook). The javascript event handler in my xhtml page then calls the following remotecommand:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateWidget"
             autoRun="false"
             actionListener="#{parliamentManager.findLatestPrices}"
             update="resultDisplay"
             onstart="onStart()"
             oncomplete="onComplete()"
             onsuccess="onSuccess()"
             onerror="onError()">
             <f:actionListener binding="#{parliamentManager.findTraders()}"  />
             <f:actionListener binding="#  {parliamentManager.findPortfolios()}" />
             </p:remoteCommand>
```

It seems that often the results of findLatestPrices does not include the latest OrderBook entities for all sessions. Is it possible that an entity is not persisted immediately on a call to @PostPersist, working on the theory that the push is sent to some sessions before the entity is fully persisted and reflected by JPA?

To demonstrate I added a simple command button to call updateWidget() manually. If the session is not updated and I click the button it always updates to the latest data.

Thanks,
Zobbo

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache before doing the query `em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply simdevmon. I tried that but it didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There is no locking between sessions, so I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Optimistic locking to prevent overwriting stale data is recommended in most JPA provider documentation.

You haven't shown or specified how you are obtaining the EntityManager, or how long it is lived, but there are two levels of caching.  The first is the EntityManager itself, which is used to track changes to manage entities and maintain their identity.  JPA allows but doesn't mandate a second level of caching, shared at the EntityManagerFactory level.  This second level of cache is what the javax.persistence.cache.storeMode is aimed at - it controls what happens when entities are pulled from the shared cache. If the entities are already loaded in the first level cache, because this is meant to represent a transactional scope, they are returned as-is, preserving any unsynchronized changes the application might have been made and JPA provider is required to track.

The only way JPA gives to force a refresh of a managed entity is by calling em.refresh(), though it can also be accomplished by calling em.clear, then re-reading the entity using the javax.persistence.cache.storeMode refresh hint.  EclipseLink also has an "eclipselink.refresh" query hint that can be used to force the query to refresh the managed entity instance.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply. I just create the EntityManager by using @PersistenceContext, I've edited my post to illustrate.

Comment: I've tried the above suggestion (clearing the cache and then using the refresh hint) but that didn't work. I can't really call refresh since I'm returning a list of entities and the problem is there are entities missing from the list. Since the evictall suggestion by simdevmon didn't work either I'm beginning to wonder if it is the cache at all and not some logic issue.

Comment: Verify what is in the database directly then, as JPA can't read what isn't there.

Comment: Thanks Chris, though I haven't done this yet I've added a bit more detail to the original question. I intend to add sql logging to see if I can figure out what is going on

Comment: Your update completely changes things.  PostPersist executes after the insert statement, but the transaction hasn't comited yet so it isn't visible to other connections/sessions.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think I can get this to work using something like this:

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724029/check-whether-a-jta-transaction-is-successfully-committed